# Building a Debian-based Linux Distro Online

Tags: linux, debian, opensuse, distributions

[susestudio](http://susestudio.com) provides an online tool for building one's own `Redhat-based` `Opensuse linux` distro. However, I am more of a `Debian-based` guy.
I was wondering of there is a similar website that let's us build `Debian-based Linux` distros?

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do with [Debian Live Build](http://live-build-cgi.debian.net/cgi-bin/live-build) and select yes in Debian Installer.